# Is fear of flying far more pervasive than fear of driving?

Tags: behavior

The textbook example of risk perception is flying vs driving, namely that flying is scary but safe and driving is dangerous. It's true the per mile or even per hour flight *on airlines* in the US is safer than driving. However, is is also true that far more people are *afraid* of flying? There are several reasons to believe the contrary:

**Cliche:** Since flying vs driving is such a well-used comparison, the message will get through to some people.

**Close calls:** Proportionally few people have had a close call on flying (though turbulence can *feel* like a close call). In driving, most people not only had close calls but have had crashes or know people who had serious car crashes.

**Travel stress:** Flying is *very stressful* (planning, security, jet lag, etc), so that can create many symptoms of fear (anxiety) or exacerbate an otherwise minor level of fear. We would like to separate the effect of fear itself from the other sources of angst.

**Passive vs active:** Many strategies for flying phobia (drugs, books, etc) rely on getting the mind away from the activity. This is impossible when driving.

Given all these caveats, is the fear of flying debilitating to more people than the fear of driving? "Debilitating" means how much it impacts quality of life. Taking a pill is less so than losing sleep the night before traveling, which in turn is less than not being able to fly at all.

Comment: Is "Fear of flying is more pervasive than fear of driving" a notable claim? Can you find notable examples of people making this claim?

Comment: There are heaps and heaps. Here's one where it's explicitly taken for granted in the headline https://io9.gizmodo.com/5846218/why-youre-more-afraid-of-flying-than-driving-to-the-supermarket/amp

Comment: I don't think you can really count "travel stress" as fear of flying.  Flying itself doesn't bother me at all - I've held a pilot's license for decades, and own my own plane - but I won't fly commercial except at very great need, because I don't want to be subject to airline security or be jammed into a too-small seat on a crowded plane.

Comment: Pervasive is a funny word there, mass hysteria in an airplane can be pervasive, but if you are alone driving a car this doesn't apply. In general the difference between fear of flying and driving is from the lack of control (you are likely to not be the airplanes pilot but likely to be the cars driver - unless we are talking about full blown rain man phobia people who dont have to drive anything).

Comment: I think that fear is real, though not justified.  People who don't understand the mechanics of lift just see a huge, huge, heavy object that should not be able to "float" in the air (which, it doesn't), so there's a certain amount of fear of unknown, or poorly understood. There's also the fact that when things do go wrong, they do so in a more spectacular fashion. Finally, there's the perception of control vs having no control, or, if you're a passenger in each case, at least being able to observe the control, in real time.

Comment: _"Many strategies for flying phobia (drugs, books, etc) rely on getting the mind away from the activity. This is impossible when driving."_ Based on this quote, it seems like you are comparing flight **passengers** with car **drivers**, and are excluding car passengers (who could actually distract themselves). This leaves it open for the fear of flying being a fear of _not being in control_ as opposed to a fear for the specific _mode of transportation_. Anecdotally, all people I know as "cautious" car passengers (= somewhat afraid) have all shown a fear of flying to a similar extent.

Comment: @Flater: Yes you are right. I am looking at common activities people need to do. Very few people actually need to be pilots, but driving is hard to get away without. Being a passenger is also common but I fear driving much more than being a passenger, so was interested in driving in particular.

Comment: "I fear driving much more than being a passenger" I think this reveals a lack of confidence in your own skills (why would you feel safer as a passenger than as a driver, except if you feel relatively underskilled as a driver?), which in turn can make you more accepting of flying on a plane that is controlled by someone who is not you. There are a lot of factors here: self-confidence, trust, personal skills. I trust my own driving but I wouldn't trust my own flying (as I have had no formal training). Others might always defer to others (like you?). Others might always trust themselves more.

Comment: @Flater: Correct. Is my case the usual or am I an exception? This is one reason why I am asking this question. Are more people afraid of their own skill driving or afraid of the "un-naturalness" and/or "lack of control" when flying. Which one is more common?

Comment: Because of the many factors involved, I doubt we'll be able to deduce this logically. There are so many personal experiences that can skew your fear of one but not the other. I think the best way to find this out is through polling people.